# Android Google+ integration - repeated UserRecoverableAuthException

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-plus

*We have contacted Google about this and [we are on chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33772/discussion-between-lee-and-arkaaito)*

*The issue seems to be fixed for devices **except** Samsung phones.*

I'm adding a Google+ sign in option to an app per the [official instructions](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in#server-side_access_for_your_app).  Once the user has selected their account I would like my server to retrieve their Google+ profile info and update their profile on our site to match.

The first part - having the user select a Google account locally - seems to work just fine.  When I try to request a token for the selected account, the Google auth dialog displays with the appropriate parameters; however, when I authorize the app using that dialog and re-request the token, `GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(...)` again throws a `UserRecoverableAuthException` (`NeedPermission`, not `GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityException`) and I get the same dialog asking me to approve!

**This behavior is present on a Samsung S3 running Android 4.1.1 (with 3 Google accounts) and an Acer A100 running 4.0.3.  It is NOT present on an HTC Glacier running 2.3.4.  Instead, the HTC Glacier gives me a valid auth code.**  All devices have the latest iteration of Google Play Services installed and are using different Google+ accounts.

Anyone seen this before?  Where can I start with debugging?

Here's the complete code - is anything obviously awry?

```
public class MyGooglePlusClient {
private static final String LOG_TAG = "GPlus";
private static final String SCOPES_LOGIN = Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN + " " + Scopes.PLUS_PROFILE;
private static final String ACTIVITIES_LOGIN = "http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity";
private static MyGooglePlusClient myGPlus = null;
private BaseActivity mRequestingActivity = null;
private String mSelectedAccount = null;
    
/**
 * Get the GPlus singleton
 * @return GPlus
 */
public synchronized static MyGooglePlusClient getInstance() {
    if (myGPlus == null)
        myGPlus = new MyGooglePlusClient();
    return myGPlus;
}

public boolean login(BaseActivity requester) {
    Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Starting login...");
    if (mRequestingActivity != null) {
        Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Login attempt already in progress.");
        return false; // Cannot launch a new request; already in progress
    }
    
    mRequestingActivity = requester;
    if (mSelectedAccount == null) {
        Intent intent = AccountPicker.newChooseAccountIntent(null, null, new String[]{GoogleAuthUtil.GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_TYPE}, false,
                null, GoogleAuthUtil.GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_TYPE, null, null);
        mRequestingActivity.startActivityForResult(intent, BaseActivity.REQUEST_GPLUS_SELECT);
    }
    return true;
}

public void loginCallback(String accountName) {
    mSelectedAccount = accountName;
    authorizeCallback();
}
    
public void logout() {
    Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Logging out...");
    mSelectedAccount = null;
}

public void authorizeCallback() {
    Log.w(LOG_TAG, "User authorized");

    AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String token = null;
            try {
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putString(GoogleAuthUtil.KEY_REQUEST_VISIBLE_ACTIVITIES, ACTIVITIES_LOGIN);
                token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(mRequestingActivity,
                        mSelectedAccount,
                        "oauth2:server:client_id:"+Constants.GOOGLE_PLUS_SERVER_OAUTH_CLIENT
                        +":api_scope:" + SCOPES_LOGIN,
                        b);
            } catch (IOException transientEx) {
                // Network or server error, try later
                Log.w(LOG_TAG, transientEx.toString());
                onCompletedLoginAttempt(false);
            } catch (GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityException e) {
                Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Google Play services not available.");
                Intent recover = e.getIntent();
                mRequestingActivity.startActivityForResult(recover, BaseActivity.REQUEST_GPLUS_AUTHORIZE);
            } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException e) {
                // Recover (with e.getIntent())
                Log.w(LOG_TAG, "User must approve "+e.toString());
                Intent recover = e.getIntent();
                mRequestingActivity.startActivityForResult(recover, BaseActivity.REQUEST_GPLUS_AUTHORIZE);
            } catch (GoogleAuthException authEx) {
                // The call is not ever expected to succeed
                Log.w(LOG_TAG, authEx.toString());
                onCompletedLoginAttempt(false);
            }

            Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Finished with task; token is "+token);
            if (token != null) {
                authorizeCallback(token);
            }
            
            return token;
        }

    };
    task.execute();
}

public void authorizeCallback(String token) {
    Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Token obtained: "+token);
    // <snipped - do some more stuff involving connecting to the server and resetting the state locally>
}

public void onCompletedLoginAttempt(boolean success) {
    Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Login attempt "+(success ? "succeeded" : "failed"));
    mRequestingActivity.hideProgressDialog();
    mRequestingActivity = null;
}
}
```

Comment: I'm still getting repeated UserRecoverableAuthException more than a year after this post. The oauth sequence keeps asking for offline permission. I suspect that GoogleAuthUtil.getToken doesn't deal correctly with access_type=offline.

Answer (score 13):

I've had this issue for a while and came up with a proper solution.

```
String token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(this, accountName, scopeString, appActivities);
```

This line will either return the one time token or will trigger the UserRecoverableAuthException.
On the Google Plus Sign In guide, it says to open the proper recovery activity.

```
startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), RECOVERABLE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

When the activity returns with the result, it will come back with few extras in the intent and that is where the new token resides :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == RECOVERABLE_REQUEST_CODE && responseCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extra = intent.getExtras();
        String oneTimeToken = extra.getString("authtoken");
    }
}
```

With the new oneTimeToken given from the extra, you can submit to the server to connect properly.

I hope this helps!

Comment: This answer should be marked correct. It is the proper way to handle the non-acquisition of the token.

Answer (score 5):

Its too late to reply but it may help to people having same concern in future.

They have mentioned in the [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in#enable_server-side_api_access_for_your_app) that it will always throw UserRecoverableAuthException 
when you invoke GoogleAuthUtil.getToken() for the first time. Second time it will succeed.

```
catch (UserRecoverableAuthException e) {
  // Requesting an authorization code will always throw
  // UserRecoverableAuthException on the first call to GoogleAuthUtil.getToken
  // because the user must consent to offline access to their data.  After
  // consent is granted control is returned to your activity in onActivityResult
  // and the second call to GoogleAuthUtil.getToken will succeed.
  startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), AUTH_CODE_REQUEST_CODE);
  return;
}
```

i used below code to get access code from google.

execute this `new GetAuthTokenFromGoogle().execute();` once from `public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint)`    and once from `protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent intent)`

```
private class GetAuthTokenFromGoogle extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>{
        @Override  
        protected void onPreExecute()  
        {  

        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try {
                accessCode = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(mContext, Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient), SCOPE);
                new ValidateTokenWithPhoneOmega().execute();
                Log.d("Token  -- ", accessCode);
            } catch (IOException transientEx) {
                // network or server error, the call is expected to succeed if you try again later.
                // Don't attempt to call again immediately - the request is likely to
                // fail, you'll hit quotas or back-off.

                return null;
            } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException e) {
                // Recover
                startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), RC_ACCESS_CODE);
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (GoogleAuthException authEx) {
                // Failure. The call is not expected to ever succeed so it should not be
                // retried.
                authEx.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            return null;  
        }

        @Override  
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result)  
        { 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Would you say that this method is "the correct way to do it" or "a way which seems to work well"? Also, does this work in the case where a user cancels one (or both) of the dialogs (one or more times)?

Comment: This works well in my case.

In the first call to GoogleAuthUtil.getToken() user will be presented with Offline access consent screen. Once user clicks on ok button he will see the the "Signing in" screen (only once) with a message like this may take minutes. After this, user wont see any screen, the second call to GoogleAuthUtil.getToken() will return the access code.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit (6th Aug 2013): This seems to have been fixed for me without any changes to my code.**

The first potential issue I can see is that you are calling `GoogleAuthUtil.getToken()` after you get the `onConnected()` callback.  This is a problem because requesting an authorization code for your server using `GoogleAuthUtil.getToken()` will **always** show a consent screen to your users.  So you should only get an authorization code for new users and, to avoid showing new users two consent screens, you must fetch an authorization code and exchange it on your server before resolving any connection failures from `PlusClient`.

Secondly, make sure you actually need both a PlusClient and an authorization code for your servers.  You only need to get a PlusClient and an authorization code if you are intending to make calls to the Google APIs from both the Android client **and** your server.  As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17603516/secure-google-plus-sign-in-into-web-app-via-android-app/17611792#17611792).

These issues would only result in two consent dialogs being displayed (which is clearly not an endless loop) - are you seeing more than two consent dialogs?

Comment: OK.  I wondered about this.  It seems like I have a fundamental misunderstanding about how to retrieve the token once the user has approved it - if I don't retrieve the token with a repeated call to getToken(), then how *do* I retrieve it?  (The intent passed into onActivityResult() doesn't appear to have any extras containing it, and I haven't found any other relevant methods in the API docs.)

Comment: No, you were correct in the first instance.  You need the repeated calls to getToken() to get the token after dealing with UserRecoverableAuthExceptions.  But that is not where the multiple consent dialogs come from. The double consent happens because you potentially need to resolve the UserRecoverableAuthException in order to successfully get onConnected from PlusClient.connect().  But you are then guaranteed to get another consent dialog for the authorization code call.

Comment: Hmm.  I see.  That's what you meant about it not explaining why I'm getting more than two.  But if there are multiple Google accounts on the device, don't I have to get their account selection from the result of PlusClient.connect()?

Comment: You are correct - unfortunately you cannot use the built in account selection.  Instead you need AccountPicker.newChooseAccountIntent() to present your own account chooser and then use PlusClient.Builder.setAccountName() to set the account name when you create the PlusClient.

Comment: Ah, okay.  Switched (but I still see the same behavior - even with the PlusClient and related callbacks completely removed).

Comment: Hmmm okay, that's interesting.  So what are you seeing?  With just the call to `GoogleAuthUtil.getToken()` it throws `UserRecoverableAuthException` which displays the consent dialog.  You click accept and it returns to onActivityResult(), and the next call to `GoogleAuthUtil.getToken()` throws another `UserRecoverableAuthException` which displays another consent dialog?  In an endless loop?

Comment: Yes, precisely.  I've updated the question to hopefully make the issue clearer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33772/discussion-between-lee-and-arkaaito)

Comment: Do you know if the Google Play Services version on the device got auto-updated or if there were any other changes to the device configuration that could explain it?  My devices (well - the ones I've tested so far) are still showing the same problem.

Comment: The Google Play services version is definitely the same, so I'm guessing it is a server side change. :-/

Answer (score 2):

I have got around this issue by using a web based login. I open a url like this

```
String url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=" + Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN + "&client_id=" + webLoginClientId + "&response_type=code&access_type=offline&approval_prompt=force&redirect_uri=" + redirect;
```

The redirect url then handles the response and returns to my app.

In terms of my findings on using the Google Play Services, I've found:

HTC One is 3.1.59 (736673-30) - not working
Galaxy Note is 3.1.59 (736673-36) - not working
Nexus S is 3.1.59 (736673-34) - works

And I'd like to be involved in the chat that is occurring, however I don't have a high enough reputation to do so.

Comment: Thanks for the work-around idea!  I'll check it out on my app and report back.  What are you opening the URL with - a WebView or something else?

Comment: Yeah I'm using a WebView... it's not the nicest implementation though because it doesn't matter if the user is already signed in with a G+ account on the phone, because they always have to enter their details in the WebView independently. I'm hoping that the native login can get resolved.

Answer (score 2):

I've experienced the same issue recently - it appears to be device-specific (I had it happen every time on one S3, but on another S3 running the same OS it didn't happen, even with the same account). My hunch is that it's a bug in a client app, either the G+ app or the Google Play Services app. I managed to solve the issue on one of my devices by factory resetting it (a Motorola Defy), then reinstalling the Google Play Services app, but that's a completely useless solution to tell to users.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem where an apparent auth loop kept creating {read: spamming} these "**Signing In...**" and Permission request dialogs while also giving out the discussed exception repeatedly.

The problem appears in some slightly-modified example code that I (and other like me, I suspect) ["cargo-culted"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) from [AndroidHive](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/). The solution that worked for me was **ensuring that only one background token-retrieval task runs at the background at any given time.**

To make my code easier to follow, here's the auth flow in my app (that is almost identical to the example code on AndoidHive): `Activity` -> `onConnected(...)` -> `getProfileInformation()` -> `getOneTimeToken()`.

Here's where `getOneTimeToken()` is called:

```
private void getProfileInformation() {
    try {
        if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
            Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi
                    .getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
            String personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
            String personPhotoUrl = currentPerson.getImage().getUrl();
            String personGooglePlusProfile = currentPerson.getUrl();
            String email = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);
            getOneTimeToken(); // <-------
            ...
```

Here's my `getOneTimeToken()`:

```
private void getOneTimeToken(){
    if (task==null){
    task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            LogHelper.log('d',LOGTAG, "Executing background task....");
            Bundle appActivities = new Bundle();
            appActivities.putString(
                         GoogleAuthUtil.KEY_REQUEST_VISIBLE_ACTIVITIES,
                         ACTIVITIES_LOGIN);
            String scopes = "oauth2:server" + 
                            ":client_id:" + SERVER_CLIENT_ID + 
                            ":api_scope:" + SCOPES_LOGIN;
            String token = null;
            try {
                token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(
                        ActivityPlus.this,
                        Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient),
                        scopes,
                        appActivities
                );
            } catch (IOException transientEx) {
                /* Original comment removed*/
                LogHelper.log('e',LOGTAG, transientEx.toString());
            } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException e) {
                /* Original comment removed*/
                LogHelper.log('e',LOGTAG, e.toString());
                startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), AUTH_CODE_REQUEST);
            } catch (GoogleAuthException authEx) {
                /* Original comment removed*/
                LogHelper.log('e',LOGTAG, authEx.toString());
            } catch (IllegalStateException stateEx){
                LogHelper.log('e',LOGTAG, stateEx.toString());
            }
            LogHelper.log('d',LOGTAG, "Background task finishing....");
            return token;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String token) {
            LogHelper.log('i',LOGTAG, "Access token retrieved: " + token);
        }

    };
    }
    LogHelper.log('d',LOGTAG, "Task setup successful.");
    if(task.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING){
        task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR); //double safety!
    } else
        LogHelper.log('d',LOGTAG, 
                       "Attempted to restart task while it is running!");
}
```

Please note that I have a {probably redundant} double-safety against the task executing multiple times:

1. `if(task .getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING){...}` - ensures that the task isn't running before attempting to execute it.
2. `task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR);`- makes sure that copies of this task are "synchronized" (i.e. a queue is in place such that only one task of this type can executed at a given time).

P.S.
Minor clarification: `LogHelper.log('e',...)` is equivalent to `Log.e(...)` etc.

Answer (score 0):

you should startactiviy in UI thread

```
try {
    ....
} catch (IOException transientEx) {
    ....
} catch (final UserRecoverableAuthException e) {
    ....
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {         
            startActivityForResult(e1.getIntent(), AUTH_CODE_REQUEST);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same bug with infinite loop of permission request. For me it was because time on my phone was shifted. When I check detect time automatically this bug disappeared. Hope this helps!