# weird notification warning when trying to sign in with google account in Android

Tags: android, authentication, google-plus, google-signin

I'm kinda new to Google SDK and I'm trying to implement a Google sign-in button in my app so users can login with their Google accounts. 
I've added a `SignInButton` and handled the basic authentication flow with a `PlusClient` object. I also use an `AsyncTask` to get the Auth Token from `GoogleAuthUtil`. once I successfully get the token, I call `LoginActivity.finish()` and allow access to my app.

When I click the `SignInButton` I get the following:

1. prompts a window to choose between my google accounts.
2. A permissions screen asking me to confirm that this app would like to know your name, basic info etc.. to which I click OK.
3. a weird notification warning icon (triangle with exclamation mark inside) that says "sign-in request"
4. after clicking the notification, I see a quick "signing in.." screen for a few seconds and then back to step 2 - to which I click ok again.
5. clicking the sign in button again logs me in successfully.

This flow is obviously not as it should be, so my questions are:

- Why do I get the ask for permissions screen twice? and also everytime I try to login?
- How do I get rid of that weird warning notification and just login when finished?

Using Android SDK v4.2 with Play Services SDK v10

**EDIT**

Ok, so kind of a stupid question, but I still haven't figured it all out yet.
It turns out I was using `GoogleAuthUtil.getTokenWithNotification` which sends a push notification if the method fails with a recoverable action. So I changed it back to `GoogleAuthUtil.getToken` and now I recover it programmatically which is better. 
But I still get the intervention screen, once when I call `result.startResolutionForResult` inside `onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result)` when I try to connect and the second time after calling `startActivityForResult` when calling `GoogleAuthUtil.getToken`. This is still a mystery...

**EDIT 2**

The first question (second one is answered above)) about repeated permissions prompted to the user is discussed in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17713435/android-google-integration-repeated-userrecoverableauthexception)